# Fast data search on Azure - what's the right product?

Tags: azure, search, azure-sql-database, azure-hdinsight

I have a basic email client and want to allow users to query all their emails (from, recipients, subject, and plain text) for key words (like the search feature in gmail). I want to return the top 50 emails (by chronological order) from the search.

Currently we store the plain text of the email in SQL Server and just search that. But we want to maximize performance and hedge against growing data and I know this won't scale well.

My guess is that HDInsight is the fastest product in azure for search. But is this the right tool for this? Would it be faster than enabling full text search on my SQL Server (which is an azure sql server database)?

What's the right tool (in Azure) for this?

Comment: HDInsight isn't a search tool; it's a map/reduce engine. Tool recommendation questions  are off-topic for StackOverflow, but I suggest you look at the database and search offerings (including search-as-service) documented at azure.com, each with varying performance specs (and look at Virtual Machines too, which would allow you to run a full text search engine of your choosing). I'd suggest asking follow-up questions that are more objective in nature.

Comment: Wow you answered my question~! Haha. Didn't even know about azure search. I think that's my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either Azure search or SQl Azure full-text search. Full-text search is less costly option in terms of implementation but will be a quick fix for your solution. Long term depending on the volume of data you can choose one of them

Comment: Azure search is the right answer.